# How to add conditions in laravel auth

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 5.8.

I want to add `email_verified_at != null OR phone_number_verified_at != null` in auth.

How do I do that?

Comment: If i am not wrong, you're trying to prevent access from unverified user to app right? You can use a route middleware.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in web.php route `Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);`
Read this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/verification#verification-routing

if you are using this its check email verified or not `Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);`

If you want to more about go to this path in laravel project `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth` and see trait MustVerifyEmail

```
public function hasVerifiedEmail()
{
    return ! is_null($this->email_verified_at);
}
```

You are trying to check both

overite one method

```
    public function hasVerifiedEmail()
{
    if (!is_null($this->phone_verified_at) && !is_null($this->email_verified_at)) {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

2.step go to `VerificationController`

```
    /**
 * Show the email verification notice.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    if (is_null($user->email_verified_at)) {
        return view('auth.verify');
    }elseif (is_null($user->phone_verified_at)) {
        return redirect("phone_verify");
    }else{
         return redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
}
```

go to `web.php` create route for phone verify

```
Route::get('phone_verify',function(){
   dd("not verify");
});
```

Comment: I just want to filter the auth query

Comment: check this editing my code its better you use default functions 
if you are using go to login controller and overite login function and `Auth::user()->phone_verify_at and check value null or not return message

Comment: i do some changes in `VerificationController` in `show` method

Answer (score 1):

Add `attemptLogin` function in LoginController, this function is called by laravel to authenticate

```
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    $valid = $this->guard()->attempt(
        $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
    );
    if($valid){
        $user = $this->guard()->user();
        if($user->email_verified_at == null && $user->phone_number_verified_at  == null ){
            $this->guard()->logout();
            $request->session()->invalidate();
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Praveen , your method works, but is there a way to customize the message error displayed in that case ?

Comment: @loli Please refer to https://github.com/guiwoda/laravel-framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L126 for customized error message

Comment: Hi Parveen, I actally added to your solution as below:
    protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)//this will get triggered if the method above (attemptLogin(Request $request))  returns false.
    {
        $errors = [$this->username() => trans('auth.notactivated')];
        return redirect()->back()
            ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
            ->withErrors($errors);
    }